# Ringtone not playing on certain Samsung devices with Android 11

Tags: android, notifications, ringtone, silent

I'm working on a VoIP app and when a call comes in, the ringtone is not audible on at least a Samsung A20e and a Samsung A71 device running on Android 11. Unfortunately, this info came from a few users who say they experience the issue and the issue doesn't arise on all the phones I have access to, so I'm not able to look in the logs myself.

To get the ringtone URI, the following code is used:

```
val uri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
```

Then that URI is used on the notification channel:

```
val attributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
   .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
   .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
   .build()
notificationChannel.setSound(uri, attributes)
```

And the URI is used once again in the method `setSound` of the `NotificationCompat.Builder` to generate the actual notification.

I tried to reproduce the issue on an emulator and changed the values in `setUsage` and `setContentType` a lot, but nothing seemed to have impact. I also reinstalled the app on every change, to make sure a new notification channel would be created.

Then I read somewhere on the internet that ringtones never work on an emulator. However, I do have an emulator on which the ringtone is actually audible, so I'm not so sure that's true, at least not for every configuration.

Lastly I should add that the ringtone also wasn't silent on my original emulator when I added the following line:

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri).play()
```

However, I'm not actually able to use that piece of code, since I need to attach the ringtone to a notification (channel).

Does anyone have experience with a same type of issue? Is there a problem with the settings of my notification or the notification channel? Is this just a Samsung issue? I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. Turns out the client didn't describe the issue thorough enough and it turned out to be an easily solvable issue when he provided us with more information. The ringtone would be audible when the notification volume of the phone was on and the ringtone volume of the phone was off. However, when the notification volume was off and the ringtone volume was on, the ringtone wouldn't be audible. So the two of those got switched around, which got fixed by replacing `AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION` with `AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE`.